# How to setup a Multitenant Azure AD SSO using OIDC

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, federated-identity

I need to setup a multi-tenant app registration for letting our customer's employee signing up in our mobile application using their corporate account.

[image: A brief schema of what i need]

When you setup a multi-tenant app registration on azure you have to swap your tenant ID in OIDC urls with /common/ in url but, obviously, the token is not issued by "common" , it will be issued by a tenant.

This mismatch will cause a BAD ISSUER ERROR.

I'm missing something or Azure is not in standard with OIDC?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, you need to essentially disable issuer verification or validate the issuer URI manually. You can see in the common endpoint metadata that it is a template: https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration.

```json
{
  "issuer": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantid}/v2.0"
}
```

If you know in advance the tenant ids that you allow, you can check for those specific URIs.
Otherwise you could check if the URI matches the above format.